# StreetPass Miis arriving by invitation

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass

On the Nintendo 3DS system players can collect other Miis via StreetPass and then visit and view them in the StreetPass Mii Plaza.  But it turns out that many more Miis will show up in the plaza and they arrive by other means... perhaps by way of SpotPass (local wi-fi), though on this I am not sure.

What I'm curious to know is what are the ways for Miis to arrive at StreetPass Mii Plaza by Invitation?

These are the ones without any hats or costumes way in the back, and when you select on them they give no information except for a message - "Met via Invitation."

They don't show up at the gate to meet your Mii either.

Answer (score 4):

According to [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/625899-streetpass-mii-plaza/61592587):

> If you have the option turned on, and play *Mario Kart 7* online every person you race will get in your Mii Plaza. Also any person that you tag in *Super Mario 3D Land* will be there too. You also get them in *Sonic Generations*.
>
> They add to your Mii Plaza for the purpose of Achievements.

In other words, you get those Miis by playing online with other people by certain games.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think what I'm wondering is if this is the only way to get Miis by invitation and if it is has anyone compiled a list of the games that will send over Miis during online play.  I had also perused the GameFaq boards prior to posting the question and the sense was that people had observed how this was happening but no one seemed sure about which games supported the feature.

Comment: @frogsbottom On another thread I've found this: "You recieve these miis when either playing online with a game that allows the transferring miis or if someone has a game that streetpassed with you and it is not the same mii as their streetpass one (as in you will get two miis)." This means that if somebody uses different Miis in his games you can get different Miis from the same person.

Comment: Also, in the *Mii Maker* there's a setting that allows you to set copying rights on Miis you send to other 3DS systems. Maybe this is related.

Comment: That's what's intriguing me.  As soon as I discovered these 'by Invitation' Miis and how they came over from online play I started wondering about other possible ways they might be coming over.  My hope is that by posting here at Arqade we could maybe investigate it a little further and see about identifying any other means by which these types of Miis are transferred from system to system... for example by way of Nintendo Zone relays or some such.

Comment: And of course I'd be interested to know which games in particular do this.

Comment: Nintendo Zone should only work as SpotPass, you usually get 6 Miis at a time and they appear as normal StreetPass visiting you.